# Proof by induction involving trigonometric identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, polynomials, proof-writing

Show that the sequence of polynomials defined by the rules: $$p_0(x) = 1,\hspace{.3cm} p_1(x) = x,\hspace{.3cm} p_{n+1}(x) = 2xp_n(x) − p_{n−1}(x)$$

is the same as the polynomials defined as follows:

(a) $x=\cos(t)$

(b) $p_n(x)$ is the polynomial in $x$ which relates $\cos(nt)$ to $\cos(t)$.

I assume that I want to prove these polynomial descriptions are equivalent by showing how $\cos(nt)$ is tied to $\cos((n-1)t)$ and $\cos((n+1)t)$ then I could use trigonometric identities to carry my proof and then convert that expression back to $x$ then use proof by induction to show these two polynomials are the same. Is this the right way to approach this? One place of my confusion is how to apply trigonometric identities to show the relationship.

Comment: Yes your idea is good. Now the thing is to know those trigonometric formulae.

Comment: For reference: these are the *Chebyshev polynomials*.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. My PDE class covered Chebyshev polynomials, and while I had trouble with understanding them there, it's good to see some familiarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly that: the *addition formulæ* yield
$$\cos (a-b)+\cos(a+b)=2\cos a\cos b,$$
whence $$\cos(n-1)x+\cos(n+1)x=\cos(nx-x)+\cos(nx+x)=2\cos x\cos nx.$$